# WinJS - Accessing data contained outside of bound listView template

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs

Within a WinJS website i've got a listView bound to a WinJS.Binding.List which contains the data that needs to be repeated within listView template.  This works fine.

The issue I have is that within this template I also need to output details from an Object (called localisation) that contains localised text.  As this appears outside of the bound data mentioned above trying to access it using the below produces undefined.

```
<h1 data-win-bind="innerHTML: localisation.CertificationAdmin"></h1>
```

Put simply is there a way to access data outside of the bound data within a listView template?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that should work for you.

First, if you use a binding initializer to insert a converter, then you can define a variable in your binding context object that will, through the converter, do the resource lookup on demand.

Second, if you use a rendering function rather than a declarative template, then you can do whatever you need in the code and use whatever other objects you need.

The details of initializers/converters and template functions I've written up in Chapter 6 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2).